# FileMaker Pro 13 - how to use a button to add more fields to a record

Tags: filemaker

This is a database for logging shots on a film set.

I want to put an "add another take" button in each shot record which when pressed, it adds an additional line of fields to the record.

The reason I don't want to just add another record for every take is because I want to have only one record per shot and I need to be able to view all the takes for one shot at the same time on the same screen in a row.

I've searched all the helps and manuals I could find and haven't figured out how to do this. Help :) !

Answer (score 3):

It's not possible to change the schema programmatically. What you really want to do here is use two tables, Shots and Takes, with a one-to-many *relationship* between them. Then use a *portal* to Takes, placed on a layout of Shots, in order to "add an additional line of fields to the [shot] record".

---

### Added:

Here's an example of a script to create the necessary sub-takes.

```
Set Variable [ $takeID; Value:Takes::TakeID ] 
Set Variable [ $cameras; Value:Takes::Cameras ] 
# 
Go to Layout [ “SubTakes” (SubTakes) ] 
Loop 
Set Variable [ $i; Value:$i + 1 ] 
Exit Loop If [ $i > ValueCount ( $cameras ) ] 
New Record/Request 
Set Field [ SubTakes::TakeID; $takeID ] 
Set Field [ SubTakes::Camera; GetValue ( $cameras ; $i ) ] 
End Loop 
# 
Go to Layout [ original layout ]
```

Comment: oh wow, thanks very much, that really helps! Here's a 2nd similar question, maybe the answer is the same. Each shot has possible multiple cameras, but not always. So I want to have checkboxes within each shot record which allow me to check off A CAM, B CAM, C CAM, etc - and each camera would then also have nearly the same shot and take information, with some modifications. Do I then also make a separate table for each camera, which activates only if the camera's box is checked? Then I in turn add duplicate (with modifications) tables to each camera shot? Thanks!

Comment: @Jau You should never need to have duplicate records (with the same information). If there are multiple cameras on a shot, you should have a single Take record with fields that describe the unique take (common to all cameras). If you have additional fields that describe the individual instances of the take for each camera, then add another table (as child of Takes). If you like, you can have a script create the necessary "sub-take" records automatically.

Comment: Thanks very much @michael.hor257k, working on it now. Might throw out another question in a bit. Happy Thanksgiving.

Comment: can I ask one more related question? In Filemaker Pro, I'm trying to do a 'calculate' or a 'look up' in a field that looks up the value of the last record and adds one. All I can find is just the serial which starts the number in the wrong place if I delete records. Also, I'm looking to do a similar calculation, but to add a letter. Like if the last record was 7B, I want it to auto fill the next record to be 7C, etc. Then when it gets to 7Z, it would restart at 7AA, 7BB, etc. Any tips?

Comment: Also, is there a quick script you can show me to create a sub take for a second camera if say the B CAM checkbox is checked off on a take?

Comment: @Jau I have added a script example to my answer. Re your other question, I suggest you ask a new one. I also suggest that you explain what your ultimate goal is there, as the route you propose is not a good one to take, IMHO.

Comment: michael.hor257k - thank you, wow, advanced stuff, I just know basic html - I'll reopen a new question and put ultimate goal. I'm looking everywhere for the 'question answered' button, and cannot find anywhere to check that off.